# how to register a second page-template

Tags: php, themes, templates, user-registration

i'm using blogolife http://wordpress.org/themes/blogolife and like to add another page-tamplate which is identical to the standart page-template but has a different sidebar. also i'd like to add a business- and a contact-template. the theme-folder structure how ever is kind of confusing to me, if someone would be so nice to load the theme and check the structure, and maybe even explain to me, i would be very pleased.

also i can only select one template, even if it seems there are several sub-templates in this theme. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look at the structure, I got to say it appears pretty standard.

Simply follow the codex article on [*creating a page template*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Creating_a_Page_Template) and drop the new file in the theme's root directory. Done.

Any custom template for multiple pages should start like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: WPSE Template Example
*/
```

Comment: then, could you please tell me what the main-page-template is called, because it seems not to work with the file i duplicated (page.php) also afais there is no information like the template name inside the .php

Comment: *page.php* is the standard or main page template. Also says so in the comment block at its top. Have you actually read the codex article I linked to? You do understand that a custom template has to start with a PHP comment giving the template name?

Comment: Thanks, I added <? php /* Template Name: xyz */ ?> to the file so it got recognized by wordpress :)